# Вывод товаров по категориям в django

Tags: python, sql, django, шаблоны

Есть две модели: категории товаров и товары. Каждая модель находится в отдельном приложении Django. Цель: сделать вывод на странице заголовка категории и под ним перечень товаров данной категории. По неизвестной причине вывод товаров не осуществляется, страница загружается без каких-либо ошибок.

category.models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True, blank=True, default='')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category_view', args=[str(self.id)])
```

`product.models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, default='')
    category = models.ForeignKey('category.Category', related_name='product', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product_view', args=[str(self.id)])
```

`product.views.py`:

```
class ProductListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product/products.html'


    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

product.urls.py:

```
path('products/', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name='product_list'),
```

product/products.html:

```
  <h3>Товары</h3>
    {% if categories %}
      {% for category in categories %}
       <h3>{{ category.title }}</h3>
            {% for el in category.product_list_set.all %}
                {{ el.title }}
            {% endfor %}
       {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

В результате загружается страница, где отображаются заголовки категорий, но не отображаются товары.

Или отобразить все товары данной категории на странице этой категории. Но каким образом в `DetailView` получить `id` нужной категории?

```
class CategoryDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'category/category_detail.html'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context['products'] = Product.objects.filter(category=<category_id)
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне удалось найти следующее решение:
Вывод товаров всех товаров, принадлежащих категории, на странице самой категории.

views.py :

```
class CategoryDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'category/category_detail.html'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context['products'] = Product.objects.filter(category=self.object.id)
        return context
```

category/category_detail.html :

```
{% block content %}
<h3>{{ category.title }}</h3>
{% if products %}
   {% for product in products %}
      {{ product.title }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Но, к сожалению, так и не знаю как реализовать фильтрацию в шаблоне аналогичную `Product.objects.filter(category=<category_forein_key>)`

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.